# Stop heartbeat from failing over on failures

Tags: linux, centos, heartbeat

I have 2 CentOS machines with Heartbeat.  If `node01` has a problem or reboots, `node02` takes over -- this works.

After `node01` comes back up, `node01` is no longer my primary which is great (`node02` has taken over). But when I reboot `node02`, `node01` becomes the primary again.

I don't want `node01` to become primary again. I want to wait for `node02` to come up as the primary.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why would you want a HA configuration to *not* fail over to a working node when the other node goes away?

Comment: they are both Mysql servers. I don't want to take any chances. If my Master server goes down (reboot, service goes up and down) I want node02 to take over and in the meantime I'll fix Node01 but I prefer that if for some reason node02 goes down then I lose the HA. is that possible?

Comment: I seriously doubt it.  You probably want to do manually-triggered failovers (stop one, start the other) anyway, given that want to take no chances.

Comment: I think this question is valid and good. There might be reasons to prevent a failback until the source of the problem has been found and eliminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid a "ping-pong" situation or want to check the system before it is ready to take over services again, I would recommend to

- Start heartbeat manually after system boot `chkconfig heartbeat off`
- Stop heartbeat after failover on the failed node.

The latter is a little bit tricky - but you could define a resource in your mysql-resource-group that stops heartbeat (but I would not recommend that - since you are shooting at your own feet that way).

This might be better outside heartbeat-control (perhaps a script that checks if `cl_status rscstatus` returns **none** and then stops heartbeat.